# Dealing with UPDATEing from another table when the JOIN is multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm dealing with UPDATEing from another table when the JOIN is multiple columns

I've tried numerous versions of a SQL statement, but none of them work correctly.

I need to update single fields from one table with data from another table, but the JOIN is on three fields.  Sometimes I need to update with SUM() from other fields.

So here's the problem:
I'm dealing with this maddening Property Management software that has NO IDENTITY FIELDS!!!  (Why?  Why would you not use identity fields?!?!?!)

As a result, my linking always involves:  dept_no (unique to each property), unit (each unit), lease start date (because there can be multiple leases for each property/unit combination).

I already have a "Lease_unit" table I generated that gave me the MAX(lease_start_date) for each property/unit combination.  But then, I often need to update fields in that table with data from other sources, where the link is that dept_no, unit, lease_start_date combination (don't need the MAX() as I've already taken care of that).

So, there's two kinds of problems/examples I cannot figure out that some of you folks can answer in a second (which I've been pounding my head against a wall with for a while).  Can someone help me?

Problem/Example #1:

```
Update lease_unit.field with other_table.other_field
     where lease_unit.dept_no = other_table.dept_no AND lease_unit.unit = other_table.unit AND lease_unit.lease_start_date = other_table.lease_start_date.
```

Problem/Example #2:

```
Update lease_unit.field with SUM(other_table.numeric_field)
    where lease_unit.dept_no = other_table.dept_no AND lease_unit.unit = other_table.unit AND lease_unit.lease_start_date = other_table.lease_start_date.
```

I could really use some guidance here.  I really appreciate anyone who could give me a few minutes of your time.  Hopefully, some day I'll be able to pass it along to someone else.
-- John Kiernan

Comment: An update with a JOIN is the same syntax no matter how many columns are used in the JOIN condition.  I don't see why it's a "problem" that your tables don't have Identity fields.  It's not clear from the pseudo queries that you posted what you were doing wrong in your actual attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example 1
You could use update with join

```
Update lease_unit 
SET  lease_unit.field= other_table.other_field
FROM lease_unit 
INNER JOIN other_table ON lease_unit.dept_no = other_table.dept_no 
    AND lease_unit.unit = other_table.unit 
        AND lease_unit.lease_start_date = other_table.lease_start_date
```

EXAMPLE 2  use an update with join based on subquery for sum

```
 Update lease_unit 
 SET  lease_unit.field= t.my_sum
 FROM lease_unit 
 INNER JOIN (
  select  dept_no, unit, lease_start_date, sum(numeric_field) my_sum
  from  other_table
  GROUP BY dept_no, unit, lease_start_date

 ) t ON lease_unit.dept_no = t.dept_no 
      AND lease_unit.unit = t.unit 
          AND lease_unit.lease_start_date = t.lease_start_date
```

(anyway using an indentity column  or 3 column primary key is not a problem)